# AwesomeWM - How to change statusbar font colors and font itself

Tags: window-manager, awesome-wm

My current awesome WM theme has some ugly colors that I want to change and I want to change the font from what I believe is Terminus to Monospace. This is all for the status bar at the top btw.

```
-- Menubar configuration
menubar.utils.terminal = terminal
-- }}}
```

Is the only thing relating to Menubar in my rc.lua

Comment: I also changed stuff in theme.lua and when I restarted none of the changes were applied.

Answer (score 10):

I just fixed this for myself. In the `theme.lua` file for my active theme, I had this:

```
theme.font = 'sans 8'
```

I changed it to `inconsolata 13`, restarted awesome, and the status bar auto-expanded to fit the new font.

As for font color, you can change that with the theme.fg_* settings (theme.fg_normal, theme.fg_focused, theme.fg_urgent).

Comment: ... What about the font color tho?

Comment: I'm using the default theme, and although this works using `theme.font = "16"` there is zero padding around the text, and it overlaps with the tiny squares.